# Homebrew is not working anymore. "The i18n gem is not available"

Tags: ruby, macos, command-line, homebrew

I am not able to use homebrew anymore on my mac (version 10.15.2). When I try to use `brew` in terminal I get the error below.

It seems like I have to add the i18n Gemfile, but I am not familiar with Ruby.

```
The i18n gem is not available. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
Traceback (most recent call last):
    34: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
    33: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
    32: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    31: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    30: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    29: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    27: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    26: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/duration.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    21: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    20: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    18: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    17: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    15: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    14: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    12: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    11: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     8: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     5: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/i18n.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.2/lib/i18n.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- i18n/version (LoadError)
```

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall Homebrew?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the `i18n` gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem by simply reinstalling homebrew. I think it had to do with my last mac update.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```